# Need to connect Quickbooks Enterprise Desktop with PHP script

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks

I am new to Quickbooks.

I have installed Quick books Enterprise Desktop on my system (http://enterprisesuite.intuit.com/campaigns/dr/qbes-trial.jsp). I have downloaded php sdk files from this url ( https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php ).

Now I need to connect the Quick books Desktop with Php. I don't have any idea.

Before the time I tried with Quick books Online. So I created one app in https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/app/dashboard . So I got all of credentials from that app and I ran the script. It is worked.

But now, I need to do the same with Quickbooks Desktop. So I downloaded Php script from GitHub and downloaded the Desktop application. But I could not connect those. Actually I don't have an idea.

How can I connect my PHP script with the Quick books Desktop application? So I can add customers,vendors,invoices and handle accounting through my PHP script.

Comment: Did you follow the QUICK START GUIDE that's on the very page you linked to? https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php#quick-start-guides   Where are you stuck? What's the error message? What have you done so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: my client need to implement the Quickbooks Enterprise with php script. So that every time inventory and invoice will be updated. 

I followed your link guidance. I did install Webconnector in mine system. But i hve a doubt. 

How it will work. Please explain me if you can. Please. I dont have any idea.

Comment: Additional documentation on how the Web Connector works is available online: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks and via a 100-page PDF in the QuickBooks SDK. Both of those resources give a very good description of how the Web Connector and QuickBooks SDK work. Unless you actually post some code and actually tell us what you've done so far, in detail, you're not going to be able to get help on StackOverflow.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.   I tried your links. Below steps are i done. 
1) Downloaded and installed Quickbooks Enterprise
2) Downloaded and installed Webconnector for my sample company file
3) Dowloaded the quickbooks-php library from your github page and applied.

For Webconnector, What i url i have to give for <AppSupport> in .qwc file. ? 

How can i do all the actions with the <AppSupport> url. Example: If i give any url like 'dev/qbwc_tester.php' (it is having just one action called "CustomerAdd") for <AppSupport>, how it will be useful to do all other actions.

Comment: You can set AppSupport to the same thing as AppURL. You should absolutely NOT be setting AppSupport to dev/qbwc_tester.php. Your endpoint can have as many actions as you want - you queue something up, and then based on $map the functions execute when the Web Connector connects. If you need more help, post your code.

Comment: Fabulous help. Thanks Keith. Also I need one clarification. first action is direct action, after that all actions are in queue. Am I right?  If so, How it will read my queue actions, how it will take parameters for the actions? From Database? I am sorry, If I misunderstood.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Do you have any video tutorial or guidance for this? That will be helpful to me. If so send me the link please. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Every action is in the queue. Every. Single. One. If you're still having trouble, post your code and what you're doing.